# Cannot import '<app_name>'. Check that '<Config>' is correct

Tags: python, django

[image]

Given is my folder structure.

In 'urls.py' of project-

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('apps.job_main.urls')),
]
```

In settings.py-

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    .
    .
    'apps.job_main'
]
```

[Complete error pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/DFb0DaDV)

In apps/job_main/apps.py-

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class JobMainConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'job_main'
```

Is my import correct or any suggestions would be helpful?

Django Version=3.2.4

Comment: Show the contents of `apps/job_main/apps.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have a *sub-app* named `job_main`. The problem here is in your `AppConfig`, namely that the `name` attribute is set incorrectly. As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.name) the attribute `name` is the:

> Full Python path to the application

Hence instead of `job_main` it needs to be set to `apps.job_main`:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class JobMainConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'apps.job_main'
```

Comment: Thanks it worked.And for the clarification.